# how play video in media element from shared folder in networking

Tags: c#, windows, video, uwp

i want play video in media element from shearing file in networking . how can do it ?

for example my local IP is 192.168.1.51 and shared folder name is 'SharedFileVideo' . i can access this file from windows explorer with \192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo\video.mp4 but when i use \192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo or file://192.168.1.51/SharedFileVideo/video.mp4  in Uri for source of element media doesn't play my video .

how can bind video from file shared in networking for medial element in uwp .

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play a video file in shared folder on network, we can get the [**StorageFile**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile) first and then use the [**SetSource**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br244338.aspx) method to set the source to the file. To access files in the shared folder, we need declare some capabilities in the app manifest.
[image]
Universal Naming Convention (UNC) is the naming system commonly used in Microsoft Windows for accessing shared network folders. For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations).

So we can set **Package.appxmanifest** like following:

```xml
<Applications>
  <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="UWPApp.App">
    <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="UWPApp" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="UWPApp" BackgroundColor="transparent">
      <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
      </uap:DefaultTile>
      <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    </uap:VisualElements>
    <Extensions>
      <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
        <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="myvideotest">
          <uap:DisplayName>MyVideoTest</uap:DisplayName>
          <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:FileType>.mp4</uap:FileType>
          </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
      </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>
  </Application>
</Applications>
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
  <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
</Capabilities>
```

And then in code-behind, retrieve the shared folder first.

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo");
```

After this, we can retrieve the video file and set it as `MediaElement`'s source like:

```
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
MediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

Comment: hi many thanks just one thing . i test and know should insert \ after share folder for good working .

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting your source to:

\\192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo\video.mp4

back slashes (\) not forward slashes (/) and make sure to start with a double back slash

i do this with my raspberry pi and it gets them fine

\\RASPBERRYPI\Films\OS1\Films\video.mp4

dont forget to do this in xaml youll need this:

```
<MediaElement Source="\\192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo\video.mp4"/>
```

or for binding:

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding Path=URI}"/>
```

and in code:

```
URI = @"\\192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo\video.mp4";
```

as i said this works fine for me, i dont need synchronous programming and my machines and routers seem good enough not to cause lag or buffering issues

one other thing to remember if binding the source to a string then sometimes the media element needs telling to play. if so dont forget to tell it your manually loading video with the loaded behaviour tag.

so xaml:

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoPlayer" Source="{Binding Path=URI}" LoadedBehaviour="Manual"/>
```

and in code add:

```
URI = @"\\192.168.1.51\SharedFileVideo\video.mp4";
VideoPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: if you are using MVVM let me know and i'll show you how i achieve this without sending the media element to your viewmodels, if not the ignore this comment

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I'm testing on my desktop, the shared file is on another desktop in the same network. Have you test on desktop? Do you know why this didn't work on desktop? @Jay's answer works. But it seems too complex.

Comment: ive tried this at home with windows 8 laptop and raspberry pi and at work between 2 windows 7 pcs. all works fine. only i dont use ip i use machine name e.g \\RaspberryPI\Films\MeBeforeYou.av or \\FEDEMOWS2\Downloads\Sample.mp4

Comment: do you see the machine in question in your network section of the windows explorer? this might be the issue you have?